# Remove link in wp_list_categories list

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, wp-list-categories

I'm displaying a hierarchical list of my taxonomy "fachbereiche" using following code:

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'fachbereiche',
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'title_li'     => '',
  'feed_type'       => '',
  'child_of'     => 12
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

The displayed list is almost good, only problem is that every taxonomy list-item is wrapped in a link-tag and links to a single page of the taxonomy (which I don't have and want). How can I prevent the lists from being wrapped in an a-tag?

[The output of the list in the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm9zi.jpg)

Comment: Hello there, have you seen this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23606/how-do-i-list-custom-taxonomy-terms-without-the-links Let me know if it helped

Comment: @Kevin.a I've gone through a lot of solutions, but when I'm using get_the_terms I'm having problems with the hierarchical thing (parents and children in list) and with wp_list_categories I'm not able to remove the links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [get_term_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children).

```
<?php
    $term_id = 12;
    $taxonomy_name = 'fachbereiche';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above "sorta" works, it's not actually "removing" the links but just creating your own output.

**To actually remove the links, you could do something like this:**

```
function smyles_strip_a_tags_from_wp_list_categories( $output, $args ) {
    return strip_tags( $output, '<ul><li>' );
}

add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'smyles_strip_a_tags_from_wp_list_categories', 9999, 2 );

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'fachbereiche',
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'title_li'  => '',
    'feed_type' => '',
    'child_of'  => 12
);
?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>

<?php
remove_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'smyles_strip_a_tags_from_wp_list_categories', 9999 );
```

The gist of this is that we're adding a filter on `wp_list_categories` before we call `wp_list_categories` to call our function that strips all tags except for `<ul>` and `<li>` tags (essentially removing the links), ***and then we remove that filter after our output.***